# How to open separate window for each user

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms, authentication

I want to make a login form which open separate window for each user
 type. In this program database have 3 columns.(username, password ,usertype) there are 3 user types in this program (admin, manager, user) & each user type have separate window.

1. admin   = Form2
2. manager = Form3
3. user    = Form4

Here is my login button code. Please, help me to make this open separate
 window for each user type.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\sasindu\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Employee Database\Employee Database\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from login where username=@username and password =@password", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textBox2.Text);

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    con.Open();
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Form3 Form = new Form3();
        Form.Show();
        this.Hide();  
    }    
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter Correct Username and Password");
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have add a column in login table  user type .
user type column has derive admin,user,manager etc.
Then you will easily verify

```
if(dt.rows[0]["user_type"].tostring()=="Admin")
{
// which form you show

}

if(dt.rows[0]["user_type"].tostring()=="User")
{
// which form you show

}

if(dt.rows[0]["user_type"].tostring()=="Manager")
{
// which form you show

}
```

i hope this code help you.if any query please comment.

Comment: Instead of doing `if-else`, covert the above into `switch-case`

Answer (score 1):

```
switch (dt.Rows[0]["user_type"].ToString().ToLower())
        {
            case "admin":
            //Show Admin form
                MessageBox.Show("admin form");
                break;
            case "user":
            //Show User form
                MessageBox.Show("user form");
                break;
            case "manager":
            //Show Manager form
                MessageBox.Show("manager form");
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid user type.");
                break;
        }
```